# Fakemongo alternative available?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm developing software within a company that doesn't allow the use of Docker container. As a matter of fact, this company doesn't allow to install software on the developer machines. So, we're quite restricted in our ability to use software like MongoDb. The developers are limited in using software: we can use open source software available on github / gitlab, and most mvnrepository artifacts are available from the company nexus.

Given that context, how would developers be able to run unit tests and integration test for an application that needs to interact with MongoDb?

There's this https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo which would have been perfect. However, this doesn't implement some of the functionality we need to be able to test, e.g. searching. Are there other open source alternatives available for fongo? Or do you see other alternatives that could help us in allowing us to run unit tests against a mongodb, within the given context.

Thanks.

Comment: These things obviously seem very obvious to you, but "developing software without docker is in many cases quite expensive"? I see you've taken a shining to docker, but come on, people could afford software development even before containers. As for your problem, what's wrong with just using a test mongodb and not mocking it at all?

Comment: Why do you need to mock Mongo? If you're trying to test the actual interactions with the database, then I would think only a real instance of the same version that you'll be running in a production environment would do. For anything else, if you just want to mock the persistence of data to test the rest of your application, surely you can mock a level above?

Comment: I edited the question, to become specific,as advised.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify your reason why you want to mock mongodb.

If it is out of speed concern, you might be interested in `mongod --storageEngine ephemeralForTest` which will start an in-memory mongoDb, which, as the name already states, is not meant for production.

In fact, the `ephemeralForTest` engine runs a more recent version of mongo. You can find out by connecting to mongodb and issuing `db.version()`. In my case it's `3.5.5-13-g00ee4f5` for `ephemeralForTest` vs. `3.4.10` for default.